# Remove shipping method from quote?

Tags: shipping, quote, shipping-methods

Is there any way to remove shipping method from quote, programmatically.

I have try this code

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->unsShippingAddress();
```

but not working.

And this code is remove only from the session. How can i remove from the quote table.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
$shippingAddress->setShippingMethod('');

// Set the payment method
$shippingAddress->setPaymentMethod($paymentMethod);

// Set the payment method
$quote->getPayment()->importData(array('method' => $paymentMethod));

// Collect the prices
$quote->collectTotals()->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
<?php $shippingaddress = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress(); ?>
<?php $shippingaddress->setShippingMethod(''); ?>
<?php $shippingaddress->save(); ?>
```

but magento will throw an error saying select shipping method.you need to set something

Comment: not working. :(

Comment: for me its working.i had tested my code now.

Comment: its clear form the session. But still in quote table. How can i remove that, without remove the product from cart.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to remove current contents of shipping address. You can try this (which worked for me)

```
     $shippingaddress = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()
->getShippingAddress()->unsetData();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$shippingaddresss = $quote->getShippingAddress();
$shippingaddresss->setShippingMethod(null);
//$shippingaddresss->setShippingMethod('');
$shippingaddresss->save();
```

Set `ShippingMethod` null or empty string, both does same thing. but i recommend you to use null. 
Hope it will works. if not please share your code. 
Thanks